# why In, StdIn, StdOut is not resolved

Tags: java

I have an algorithm book and copy the code to my eclipse or one the windows cmd using `javac` to compile, the `In`, `StdIn`, `StdOut` is not resolved. I see that I have set `JAVA_HOME` to my jdk dir `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0`. What's the problem?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch {
    public static int rank(int key, int[] a)
    {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;
        while(lo <= hi)
        {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if(key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
            else if(key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] whitelist = **In**.readInts(args[0]);

        Arrays.sort(whitelist);

        while(!**StdIn**.isEmpty())
        {
            int key = **StdIn**.readInt();
            if(rank(key, whitelist) == -1)
                **StdOut**.println(key);

        }
    }
}
```

The bold classes (here enclosed by ** **) are not resolved.

Comment: Please grab a book about Java programming. Standard output is covered from basic tutorials. Also, you're not reading from standard input but from the arguments send to the application.

Comment: Is your book 'Introduction to Programming in Java' by R. Sedgewick and K. Wayne? You can get the code for the missing classes from: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/, i.e. http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdOut.java.html

Comment: One wonders what kind of "introductory" book would demonstrate the use of non-standard accessors for System.in and System.out, and not (at the very least) carefully explain what they were doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least a couple of Java programming textbooks that do not make you use standard Java, but their own classes, because this is supposedly "easier" for a beginner. One such is 'Introduction to Programming in Java' by R. Sedgewick and K. Wayne and another is 'Java: First Contact' by Garside and Mariani.

You need to download and put the custom classes on your classpath; how to do this should be described in the textbook if it is any good.

Sometimes this is done for you on a lab computer, but you would have to do it yourself on your own computer.

Comment: It's pretty idiotic for the books to do that.  How much "easier" does it make things, vs the amount of confusion (and bad habits) it causes?

Comment: Though actually I suppose it's done for the convenience of the instructors, so that they can "plug" the student program into a "harness" and feed in test input.

Comment: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib.jar here is the jar. Unjar this and add to ur project.

Answer (score -1):

The streams known as Stdin and StdOut are referred to as

```
System.in
```

and

```
System.out
```

respectively in Java.

On the first glance, it seemed that you just miss these two lines from your class:

```
static InputStream StdIn = System.in;
static PrintStream StdOut = System.out;
```

However, please note, that in Java, the naming convention specifies to use camelCased variable names, **starting with a non-capital letter**. So it should be like:

```
static InputStream stdIn = System.in;
static PrintStream stdOut = System.out;
```

<sub>(Don't forget to change the variable references inside your methods too...)</sub>
But this abstraction is rarely made, these streams are usually just referred to through the System class...

However, thanks to @harpun, who is apparently familiar with the textbook at hand, pointed out, that the classes you refer to are part of a library made for the textbook...

Comment: You mean `StdOut` ==> `System.out`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks, noticed while editing

Comment: It looks like the OP is using custom classes from http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/ and has trouble importing them and compiling his program.

Comment: @harpun thanks for clarifying, I was in the process of looking up the `isEmpty` method on the InputStream class - as I remembered that it doesn't have one...